# Google Apps Script - Digest Authentication - End to End Sample?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been playing with this for days and no luck. One of the challenges is not being able to watch the network traffic of "UrlFetch" since it is on Googles wires.

Anyone interested in posting a detailed example of using "Digest Auth" and Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, but I'm not sure I've seen it done before. I looked into it briefly once but digest authentication is pretty complicated and it's a task to code it by hand. If you are looking for a server to test against I'd recommend [test.webdav.org](http://test.webdav.org/), and there are some existing JavaScript libraries like [dijestj](http://code.google.com/p/digestj/) that you may be able to leverage or learn from.